# Загрузка массива в FloatField БД поэлементно в Django

Tags: python, django

Ребята, всем здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой, поскольку не могу найти подходящей информации в сети. У меня есть небольшой скрипт, который реализует простейшую нейронку и записывает результат в массив “pred”:

```
# Прогноз
        v_25 = float(request.POST.get('v_25'))
        v_50 = float(request.POST.get('v_50'))
        v_100 = float(request.POST.get('v_100'))
        v_300 = float(request.POST.get('v_300'))
        v_350 = float(request.POST.get('v_350'))
        v_400 = float(request.POST.get('v_400'))
        v_450 = float(request.POST.get('v_450'))
        v_500 = float(request.POST.get('v_500'))
        v_600 = float(request.POST.get('v_600'))
        v_700 = float(request.POST.get('v_700'))
        v_800 = float(request.POST.get('v_800'))
        v_900 = float(request.POST.get('v_900'))
        v_1000 = float(request.POST.get('v_1000'))
        W_out = np.array(np.random.randn(13, 6))
        W_input = np.array(np.random.randn(13, 13)) # 13 рандомных значений весов вектора
        D_m = np.array([v_25, v_50, v_100, v_300, v_350, v_400, v_450, v_500, v_600, v_700, v_800, v_900, v_1000])
        D = np.array(W_input @ D_m) # Интегральный диагностический параметр поврежденности
        goal_pred = np.array([0.982, 0.933, 0.944, 0.94, 0.925, 0.987]) # Реальный ответ, который поможет для выявления ошибок (насколько нейронная сеть ошиблась)
        alpha = 0.01
        for i in range(100):
            pred = np.round(np.array([D @ W_out]), 3) # Округляем до 3
            raznost = pred - goal_pred
            x = min(len(D), len(raznost))
            error = (pred - goal_pred) ** 2
            deriavative = np.multiply(np.array(D[:x]), np.array(raznost[:x]))
            W_out = W_out - (alpha * deriavative)
        
        print(pred)
```

Результат программа выводит на страницу:

[image: Результат 'pred']

Вопрос такой: Как можно данный массив поэлементно записать в базу данных sqlite в django?
Я попробовал прогнать с помощью цикла:

```
# Загрузка в бд
    

for data in pred:
        value = Inc1Result(
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
        )
        value.save()
```

Но результат он записывает в бд не полностью:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно потом из этой модели вытащить этот результат для составления графика в matplotlib.